# usage of "dict_value" and "dict_key" in python3

Tags: python, dictionary

`dict = {'a':1, 'b':2}`

`dict.keys` gives `dict_keys(['a', 'b'])`

`dict.values` gives `dict_values([1, 2])`.

Can someone give examples how `dict_keys` and `dict_values` come handy? Why dictionary returns these types instead of just returning a list?

I often do `list(dict.keys)` and `list(dict.values)`, converting into a list to loop over.

Comment: You can iterate over the `dict_keys` object without first expanding it to a list.  These are generator like objects.  Same for `range` in Py3 (what used to be `xrange`).

Comment: you could make a new dictionary from `dict.fromkeys(those_keys, <some_val>)` :)

Comment: @hpaulj You could just iterate over the dict keys like `for i in dict_`, so

Comment: In Python3 these are `views` which are are like snapshot of your `dict`. You can iterate over keys are internally they have `set` like structure while for values you have to convert them in `list` to actually iterate over the values

Comment: @ han solo you brought up a good point. should consider put it in answer also cover some of the basics you haven't mentioned yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you have the question the other way around: why should these methods return a list?

As the comments point out, if these methods had to return lists, then this list would have to be made first. By contrast, you can iterate over the `dict_keys` and `dict_values` objects without creating an entire big list. (You say you often cast these objects to lists, to loop over them. You don't need to do this: you can loop over the objects directly, as in `for value in my_dict.values()`.)

If you really need a list (which is usually not the case, mind you), then consider that it's better to be explicit, and create a list yourself: `x = list(my_dict.keys())`.

Comment: or just `x = list(my_dict)` :)

Comment: @hansolo Indeed that would work too! Though it wouldn't for `values` of course. (I myself am a fan of explicitly taking the keys, rather than just assuming the reader knows that iterating over a dictionary is the same as iterating over the keys. Pretty basic, but still.)

Comment: Yep, being explicit is nice, i guess. Atleast consistent with `.keys` and `.values` :)

Answer (score 3):

Doing `list(dict.keys()` takes memory for the whole created list:

```
import sys

d = {i: i for i in range(10000000)}
view = d.keys()
lst = list(d.keys())

print(sys.getsizeof(view))  # 48
print(sys.getsizeof(lst))  # 90000112
```

Creating only `dict.keys()` and iterating over it doesn't take so much memory.

`dict.keys()`, `dict.values()` and `dict.items()` return [dictionary view objects](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects). keys and items views are set-like objects, so set operations are available for them, example from this doc:

```
>>> dishes = {'eggs': 2, 'sausage': 1, 'bacon': 1, 'spam': 500}
>>> keys = dishes.keys()
>>> # set operations
>>> keys & {'eggs', 'bacon', 'salad'}
{'bacon'}
>>> keys ^ {'sausage', 'juice'}
{'juice', 'sausage', 'bacon', 'spam'}
```

Also you can create not only a `list` from these views:

```
t = tuple(keys)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use dictionary in loops no need to convert into list:

If you want values ,follow this method :

```
dict = {'a':1, 'b':2}
a=[]
for value in dict.values():
   a.append(value)
print(a)
```

**This will produce an output [1, 2]**

If you want keys ,follow this method :

```
dict = {'a':1, 'b':2}
a=[]
for key in dict.keys():
   a.append(key)
print(a)
```

**This will produce an output ['a', 'b']**

If you want both keys and values ,follow this method :

```
dict = {'a':1, 'b':2}
a=[]
for values in dict.items():
   a.append(values)
print(a)
```

**This will produce an output [('a', 1), ('b', 2)]**

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through values of the dict:

```
for v in dict.values():
    # do something
```

Through keys:

```
for k in dict.keys():
    # do something
```

Also iterates through keys:

```
for k in dict:
    # do something
```

Through items (both keys and values, this can be used to change values of the dict):

```
for k, v in dict.items():
    dict[k] = v * 2    # multiplies each value of the dict by 2
```

You can create a new dict from keys of another one (as was mentioned above):

```
d = dict.fromkeys(dict.keys(), 1)  # d will be a dictionary having keys of dict, and values all equal to 1
```